# convert pandas dataframe to json with columns as key

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df:
Col1    col2    col3    col4
 A       1        2       3
 A       4        5       6
 A       7        8       9
 B       3        2       1
 B       4        4       4
```

I want to create a nested json file for each col1 values, the inside it there will be col2, col3, col4 as keys and the value of those columns,

The output should look like:

```
{
"col1": A,
"Other_details": {
    "col2": 1,
    "col3": 2,
    "col4": 3
},{
    "col2": 4,
    "col3": 5,
    "col4": 6
},{
    "col2": 7,
    "col3": 8,
    "col4": 9
},
},
{
"col1": B,
"Other_details": {
    "col2": 3,
    "col3": 2,
    "col4": 1
},{
    "col2": 4,
    "col3": 4,
    "col4": 4
}
}
```

How to do it most efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) all columns with no `Col1` filtered by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html), create `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for dictionary output or [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) for `json` output:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Col1'])
d = (df.groupby('Col1')[cols]
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
        .reset_index(name='Other_details')
        .to_dict(orient='records'))
```

---

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Col1'])
d = (df.groupby('Col1')[cols]
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
        .reset_index(name='Other_details')
        .to_json(orient='records'))
```